# How to create a redirection for WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I have a WCF service hosted on my website A. And I have another site B, that redirects all requests to my site A using IIS URL rewriting. However, site B doesn't handle any requests to .svc files, returns 404 not found. Any idea how to make it working?

UPD redirection config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/site_A/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've found that there is no any requests to .svc files in the IIS logs of website A (!). It doesn't redirect these requests to site A. However, when I request .htm files from the site B, it redirects them to site A correctly.

Comment: So despite you redirecting them to a valid service on server B, they return 404's? We'd need to see the web.config of the service to see why the service isn't exposed (assuming the service runs fine independently). (Chances are it's permissions to the service endpoint)

Comment: did you trying using ipaddress? or the machine name instead of localhost?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but as far as I remember it may happen if you don't have http handler for .svc on web site B

Comment: Site B shouldn't handle svc requests, it should only redirect them to site A.

Comment: My guess is that if IIS doesn't know svc it can't redirect the request

Comment: Any ideas how the .svc handler should look in this case?

Comment: In web.config (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config)
under httpHandlers section
<add path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>

Comment: Usually it will appear after installing .NET Framework and some features (server roles)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were to add a .SVC handler in IIS and redirect it in the same manner as you do the .HTM requests, the redirection will not preserve the body of the message.  So a request to a service method on SiteB will not necessarily be the same as a service method call on SiteA - this depends on your configuration, whether it is exposed RESTfully, and what your bindings are.

You can have a look at [WCF 4.0's Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517422.aspx) feature.  This requires you to write certain logic to recognize a call and have it call another endpoint.

A 'cruder' solution is to simply have SiteB host a proxy service which simply accepts incoming requests and calls SiteA's equivalent service, gets the result and returns it to the caller.

Comment: "the redirection will not preserve the body of the message." : do you have a reference for this in MSDN/anywhere or is this the result of your experience?

Comment: The ASP.NET rewrite rules are simply HTTP GET based redirects.  A lot of your WCF methods, however, will be of the form HTTP POST if you look at it through Fiddler.  Those aren't handled as part of redirects which is why you need an alternate solution. As for references - I'd call it more experience but understood from the lack of documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if that is the case for all url rewriting functions (ie, in all web servers) or just IIS? Although I've been investigating with an IIS-to-IIS rewrite our client uses WebSeal as their landing web server which acts as a reverse proxy and transparently redirects to an IIS server (in their infrastructure) which hosts our web service.

Comment: I think you should start a separate question but it *sounds* like what you're looking for is Apache server's mod_proxy feature.  Detail what you want to accomplish in the question and you should get some good suggestions.  This thread isn't what you want, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need the server to handle other regular traffic including some services, one option is to create an app pool just for redirection that has no managed code.

Example:

[image: IIS With a main site of "Websites" and 2 applications: "WcfServices" and "OtherWebsites"]

Say that you want everything to http://Websites/WcfServices to redirect somewhere else.

First, make sure that URL Rewrite and ARR are installed and setup your reverse proxy. (Note that you can change the inbound rewrite rule to point to a specific path as well, not just another server)

[image: Action for Inbound Rewrite Rule with Rewrite URL set to http://internalWebServer:8080/internalWcfServices/{R:0}]

Create an app Pool for WcfServices with No Managed Code:

[image: Add Application Pool. Name: WcfServiceRedirect; .NET CLR version: No Managed Code]

Make sure that WcfServices uses the new app pool:

[image: WcfServices app's Basic Settings page with Application Pool set to WcfServiceRedirect]

At this point, WCF cannot intercept calls to something like http://Websites/WcfService/CustomerDetails.svc since no .net modules can be loaded. All traffic will be routed to the internal server set in the reverse proxy.